# NPM install on angular not working with socket.io

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

I have been working on a new project (old Angular project but new for me), after updating angular so i can use AWS Amplify everytime i try to do a `npm install` it gives me this error

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://github.com/substack/socket.io-client/tarball/master
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'socket.io-client@https://github.com/substack/socket.io-client/tarball/master' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

The weird part is that nowhere in the code theres anything to find that have the word socket. I add the `package.json` in case its usefull

```json
  "dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^14.3.0",
  "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.7",
  "@angular/common": "^14.3.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^14.3.0",
  "@angular/core": "^14.3.0",
  "@angular/flex-layout": "^14.0.0-beta.41",
  "@angular/forms": "^14.3.0",
  "@angular/material": "^14.2.7",
  "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^14.2.7",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.3.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.3.0",
  "@angular/router": "^14.3.0",
  "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
  "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.14.1",
  "application": "^0.1.4",
  "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
  "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
  "moment": "^2.29.1",
  "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
  "tslib": "^2.3.1",
  "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
  "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.12",
  "@angular/cli": "^14.2.12",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.3.0",
  "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
  "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.11",
  "@types/node": "^12.20.26",
  "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
  "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
  "karma": "~6.4.2",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
  "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
  "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
  "prettier": "^2.5.1",
  "protractor": "~7.0.0",
  "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
  "tslint": "~6.1.0",
  "typescript": "^4.0.7"
}
```

Comment: Did you try to clear local Git cache with npm cache clear

Comment: yes, i even tried instaling on a different computer and it gives the same problem

Answer (score 0):

it's possible that the package name or version in your project's package.json or any of its dependencies does not match the actual repository or version on GitHub.

and
instead of using a GitHub URL for the package, you should try using the official npm registry. Update your package.json file to include socket.io-client as a dependency without specifying a GitHub URL:

ex:

```
"dependencies": {
  "socket.io-client": "^x.x.x" // Use the appropriate version number
}
```